# Adding CCLayer to CCMenu

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer, ccmenuitem

**How can a CCLayer subclass be added to a CCMenu?** I have a CCLayer subclass that's like a switch control and I'd like to include in a CCMenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCMenu manages subclasses of CCMenuItem. You can try inherit your switch from CCMenuItem and override it's `activate` method.